# Migrations management with multiple services and a shared database

Tags: database, database-migration

I use plain sql for migrations, with the command-line tool [golang-migrate](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate).

I have multiple services that use the same database for the operations they are doing. Hence it doesn't seem right to have the same migrations (since it is a single database) duplicated in each of those services. Because it sucks having to do an update on each of the services' repository when there is a new migration. Also it logically is not clean for separate services to have the ability to update what is shared. This could cause new migrations running without other services being unaware.

Is there a standardish way of handling and managing migrations in this scenario?